# Вывод данных на график через цикл

Tags: javascript, php

имеется график со статичными данными, мне необходимо что бы данные брались из базы данных, я вывел все ок, но как правильно составить цикл что бы создавалась строка `{ x: new Date(2017,6,24), y: 31 },` и уже с динамическими данными, спасибо

**Модель**

```
public function chart() { // Вывод значений
    $params = [
        'id' => $_SESSION['account']['id']
    ];
    $data = $this->db->row("SELECT summary_mhs FROM `data` WHERE owner = :id", $params);
    $values = array_column($data, 'summary_mhs');
    $json_values = json_encode($values);
    return $chart = str_replace('"', '', stripslashes($json_values));

}

public function date() { // Вывод даты, когда была добавлена запись
    $params = [
        'id' => $_SESSION['account']['id']
    ];
    $data = $this->db->row("SELECT date FROM `data` WHERE owner = :id", $params);
    $values = array_column($data, 'date');
    $json_values = json_encode($values);
    
    return $date = str_replace('"', '', stripslashes($json_values));

}
```

**Скрпт графика**

```
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
animationEnabled: true,
title:{
    text: "Daily High Temperature at Different Beaches"
},
axisX: {
    valueFormatString: "DD MMM,YY"
},
axisY: {
    title: "Temperature (in °C)",
    suffix: " °C"
},
legend:{
    cursor: "pointer",
    fontSize: 16,
    itemclick: toggleDataSeries
},
toolTip:{
    shared: true
},
data: [

{
    name: "Nantucket",
    type: "spline",
    yValueFormatString: "#0.## °C",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: [
     { x: new Date(2017,6,24), y: 31 },
     { x: new Date(2017,6,24), y: 34 },
     { x: new Date(2017,6,28), y: 36 },
        ]
  }]
});
chart.render();

function toggleDataSeries(e){
if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
}
else{
    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
}
chart.render();
}

}
```

Comment: вот что вам точно делать не надо, то это какие-либо манипуляции после того как вы закодировали данные в json_encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужен массив пар значений, то почему вы выбираете их двумя различным методами?

сделайте нормальную выборку, например, unix timestamp из базы, будет у вас что-то вроде

```
 $data = $this->db->row("SELECT `date`, summary_mhs FROM data WHERE owner_id = :id", $params);
 return json_encode($data);
```

потом на стороне js вы каким-то образом эти данные получите и сделаете

```
 dataPoints: data.map(function(v){
                  return { x: new Date(v.date), y: +v.summary_mhs };
              }),
```